# Select Pandas dataframe rows between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, date

I am working on two tables as follows:

- A first table df1 giving a rate and a validity period:

```
rates = {'rate': [ 0.974, 0.966,  0.996,  0.998,  0.994, 1.006,  1.042,  1.072,  0.954],
'Valid from': ['31/12/2018','15/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/04/2019','15/04/2019','01/05/2019','01/06/2019','30/06/2019'],
'Valid to': ['14/01/2019','31/01/2019','28/02/2019','31/03/2019','14/04/2019','30/04/2019','31/05/2019','29/06/2019','31/07/2019']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(rates)
df1['Valid to'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Valid to'])
df1['Valid from'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Valid from'])


    rate    Valid from  Valid to
0   0.974   2018-12-31  2019-01-14
1   0.966   2019-01-15  2019-01-31
2   0.996   2019-01-02  2019-02-28
3   0.998   2019-01-03  2019-03-31
4   0.994   2019-01-04  2019-04-14
5   1.006   2019-04-15  2019-04-30
6   1.042   2019-01-05  2019-05-31
7   1.072   2019-01-06  2019-06-29
8   0.954   2019-06-30  2019-07-31
```

- A second table df2 listing recorded amounts and corresponding dates

```
data = {'date': ['03/01/2019','23/01/2019','27/02/2019','14/03/2019','05/04/2019','30/04/2019','14/06/2019'],
'amount': [200,305,155,67,95,174,236,]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])


    date        amount
0   2019-03-01  200
1   2019-01-23  305
2   2019-02-27  155
3   2019-03-14  67
4   2019-05-04  95
5   2019-04-30  174
6   2019-06-14  236
```

The objective would be to retrieve from df1 the applicable rate to each row on df2 using iteration and based on the date on df2.

Example: the date on the first row in df2 is 2019-01-03, therefore the applicable rate would be 0.974

The explanations given here (https://www.interviewqs.com/ddi_code_snippets/select_pandas_dataframe_rows_between_two_dates) gives me an idea on how to retrieve the rows on df2 between two dates in df1.

But I didn't manage to retrieve from df1 the applicable rate to each row on df2 using iteration.

Comment: looks like you need to merge ? not iterate ?

Comment: @Datanovice indeed but how could I merge if I don't have a column to join on ?

Comment: @Brahms can you please click on the check mark for the answer below if it answered your question? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframes are not very big, you can simply do the join on a dummy key and then do filtering to narrow it down to what you need. See example below (note that I had to update your example a little bit to have correct date formatting)

```
import pandas as pd

rates = {'rate': [ 0.974, 0.966,  0.996,  0.998,  0.994, 1.006,  1.042,  1.072,  0.954],
'valid_from': ['31/12/2018','15/01/2019','01/02/2019','01/03/2019','01/04/2019','15/04/2019','01/05/2019','01/06/2019','30/06/2019'],
'valid_to': ['14/01/2019','31/01/2019','28/02/2019','31/03/2019','14/04/2019','30/04/2019','31/05/2019','29/06/2019','31/07/2019']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(rates)
df1['valid_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['valid_to'],format ='%d/%m/%Y')
df1['valid_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['valid_from'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Then you `df1` would be

```
        rate    valid_from  valid_to
    0   0.974   2018-12-31  2019-01-14
    1   0.966   2019-01-15  2019-01-31
    2   0.996   2019-02-01  2019-02-28
    3   0.998   2019-03-01  2019-03-31
    4   0.994   2019-04-01  2019-04-14
    5   1.006   2019-04-15  2019-04-30
    6   1.042   2019-05-01  2019-05-31
    7   1.072   2019-06-01  2019-06-29
    8   0.954   2019-06-30  2019-07-31
```

This is your second data frame `df2`

```
data = {'date': ['03/01/2019','23/01/2019','27/02/2019','14/03/2019','05/04/2019','30/04/2019','14/06/2019'],
'amount': [200,305,155,67,95,174,236,]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'],format ='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Then your `df2` would look like the following

```
     date   amount
0   2019-01-03  200
1   2019-01-23  305
2   2019-02-27  155
3   2019-03-14  67
4   2019-04-05  95
5   2019-04-30  174
6   2019-06-14  236
```

Your solution:

```
df1['key'] = 1
df2['key'] = 1
df_output = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key').drop('key',axis=1)
df_output = df_output[(df_output['date'] > df_output['valid_from']) & (df_output['date'] <= df_output['valid_to'])]
```

This is how would the result look like `df_output`:

```
    rate    valid_from  valid_to    date    amount
0   0.974   2018-12-31  2019-01-14  2019-01-03  200
8   0.966   2019-01-15  2019-01-31  2019-01-23  305
16  0.996   2019-02-01  2019-02-28  2019-02-27  155
24  0.998   2019-03-01  2019-03-31  2019-03-14  67
32  0.994   2019-04-01  2019-04-14  2019-04-05  95
40  1.006   2019-04-15  2019-04-30  2019-04-30  174
55  1.072   2019-06-01  2019-06-29  2019-06-14  236
```

Comment: can i get a bit of a help here.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59699910/how-to-apply-the-same-function-with-different-input-arguments-to-create-new-colu

Comment: This is a very limiting approach since it fits (as you mentioned, only small data frames) what would you do for much larger data frames? the duplications in the first merge will kill the memory...