# python pandas- selecting month and day from a datetype and then inserting info on a new field

Tags: python, pandas, selection

I have 2 data frames. One, `df1`, has 20,365 rows. The other one (`df2`) 25.

`df1` looks like this:

```
Code    DateFin      ClimReg    Prec    Temp
A1      14-05-18       15A         0    15.2
A1      17-07-18       16A      0.01    28.2
B2      02-02-19       17B       2.5    -2.3
B2      30-11-18       18B       3.5    3.9
C3      14-07-18       13C       0.02   32.0
C3      15-07-18       13Z       6.3    3.9
D4      01-01-19       12I        0    -2.0
E5      01-03-18       12L       2.1    5.6
```

I need to keep in df1 ONLY the rows that are within a range shown in `df2`:

```
Code    HuntSeas      HunStart   HunEnd
A1  01-07 to 31-12    01-07-18  31-12-18
B2  15-06 to 31-01    15-06-18  31-01-19
C3  15-07 to 15-02    15-07-18  15-02-19
D4  01-07 to 28-02    01-07-18  28-02-19
E5  01-06 to 01-03    01-06-18  01-03-19..
```

That is what I pursue, an output or `df3` looking like this:

```
KanJ  DateFin   ClimReg   Prec  Temp    HuntSeas
A1   17-07-18    16A      0.01  28.2   01-07 to 31-12
B2   30-11-18    18B      3.5   3.9    15-06 to 31-01
C3   15-07-18    13Z      6.3   3.9    15-07 to 15-02
D4   01-01-19    12I       0    -2.0   01-07 to 28-02
```

The output(`df3`) should be equal or less number of rows than input (`df1`)
NOTE: my dates fields are type date

I have tried several approaches

1. It was an answer from another question: *[Select Pandas dataframe rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59699048/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)*
   however, the result is not what I expected. It gives me much more rows that in the input data frame (`df1`)
2. Since I have a lot of years to work with (not only 2018), my initial attempt was to work directly with `df1`, selecting the rows considering `MONTH` and `YEAR` from the Date field`['DateFin']`. However, I didn't find a way to do it. Would be possible to iterate through years taking month and day of a date type field?.

I will appreciate any hint that can lead me to answer this issue.
Thank you

Comment: this work for me: `df1.merge(df2, on = 'Code').query('DateFin >= HunStart and DateFin <= HunEnd')`

Comment: Thank you @Terry, I cannot believe it was so easy! I did not know the `.query` option. Put it as an answer so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `merge` with `query`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on = 'Code').query('DateFin >= HunStart and DateFin <= HunEnd')
```